# How can a user view profile info of other users?

Tags: asp.net, profile

I have stored profile info using this code

```
        ProfileBase userprofile = HttpContext.Current.Profile;
        userprofile.SetPropertyValue("FirstName", TextBoxFirstName.Text);
        userprofile.SetPropertyValue("LastName", TextBoxLastName.Text);
        userprofile.SetPropertyValue("AboutMe", TextBoxAboutMe.Text);
        userprofile.SetPropertyValue("ContactNo", TextBoxContactNo.Text);
```

and in web.config

```
<profile enabled="true"  defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider">
  <properties>
    <add name="FirstName" type="String"  />
    <add name="LastName" type="String" />
    <add name="AboutMe" type="String" />
    <add name="ContactNo" type="String" />

  </properties>
</profile>
```

The profile info is stored and every user is able to view his own profile info using something like this

```
TextBoxFirstName.Text = HttpContext.Current.Profile.GetPropertyValue("FirstName").ToString();
```

How to fetch profile info of other user say a user types the username of other user in a text box and clicks a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was looking is this below, it fetches all the profiles of the specified user.

```
ProfileInfoCollection pic = System.Web.Profile.ProfileManager.FindProfilesByUserName(ProfileAuthenticationOption.All, "username");
        foreach (ProfileInfo pi2 in pic)
        {
            //ProfileBase.Create(pi2.UserName).GetPropertyValue("FirstName").ToString();

            ListBox1.Items.Add(ProfileBase.Create(pi2.UserName).GetPropertyValue("FirstName").ToString());

            //(new ProfileBase) Create(pi2.UserName)).GetPropertyValue("FirstName");
        }
```

Answer by Hojo has been very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The below code can fetch all the user profile. Pls customise some more so that you achive your objective.

```
1       public object[] GetPropertyValues(string propertyName)
2       {
3           int totRec;
4           List<object> values = new List<object>();
5           ProfileInfoCollection pic = ProfileManager.GetAllProfiles(ProfileAuthenticationOption.Authenticated, 0, 1000, out totRec);
6    
7           foreach (ProfileInfo pi2 in pic)
8               values.Add(ProfileBase.Create(pi2.UserName).GetPropertyValue(propertyName));
9    
10          return values.ToArray();
11      }
12
```

You can get more information in http://forums.asp.net/t/1232593.aspx