# Membership Profile Property retrieval

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I am using `Membership` in .net web application.
I have the following `web.config` configuration...

```
  <profile ...>

      .....

          <properties>
               <add name="FirstName"/>
               <add name="LastName"/>
               <add name="DateOfBirth" type="DateTime"/>
               .....
          </properties>
  </profile>
```

I inserted data using the following code segment, which affected the `aspnet_profile` database table.

```
    dynamic profile = ProfileBase.Create("Username");
    profile.Initialize("Username", true);
    profile.FirstName = "someFirstName";
    profile.LastName = "someLastName";
    profile.Save();
```

Now please anyone suggest me how to retrieve this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now please anyone suggest me how to retrieve this data.

You can use [System.Web.Profile.ProfileManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profilemanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then its API like FindProfilesByUserName(), GetAllProfiles() etc.

[Here is already a solved thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479187/how-can-a-user-view-profile-info-of-other-users)

Comment: If my post helps, can you please mark it as answer, that would help others to find out solutions pretty quick.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did to retrieve profile property value...

```
string Firstname = ProfileBase.Create("UserName").GetPropertyValue("FirstName").toString();
```